# Commuting polynomials of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am proving a proposition and I notice that I can do it easily if this proposition is true:

*Let $f(t), g(t)$ two polynomials and $A\in M_n(\mathbb {F})$ a matrix such that $f(A)$ is non-singular. Then, $f(A)^{-1}g(A)=g(A)f(A)^{-1}$*

I think it is actually true, but I am having some troubles showing it. Is it true? How can I prove it?

Comment: Multiply from the right by $f\left(A\right)$ and from the left by $f\left(A\right)$ too. These are equivalent transformations since $f\left(A\right)$ is invertible. Generally, when you want to prove an equality which contains inverses that cannot directly be simplified, it is usually helpful to get rid of as many as you can by multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $f(A)$ and $g(A)$, being polynomials in $A$, commute:

$f(A)g(A) = g(A)f(A); \tag{1}$

now using the fact that $f(A)$ is invertible, we write from (1)

$g(A) = I g(A) = ((f(A))^{-1}f(A))g(A) = (f(A))^{-1}(f(A)g(A))$
$= (f(A))^{-1})(g(A)f(A)) = ((f(A))^{-1} g(A)) f(A); \tag{2}$

thus

$g(A)(f(A))^{-1} = (((f(A))^{-1} g(A)) f(A))(f(A))^{-1} = ((f(A))^{-1} g(A))(f(A)(f(A))^{-1}) = (f(A))^{-1}g(A)I = (f(A))^{-1}g(A), \tag{3}$

as requested.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that, in this case, polynomials commute

Comment: You are more than welcome!  Cheers!